# Sorting a list by last element in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I need to sort a list of IP addresses in descending order by their packet size. This is the last number in the list. For example, in the first list the packet size is 34. I'm not sure how to do this. This is what I have so far:

```
ip_list = [['192.0.80.1','208.0.0.1',34], ['192.0.80.1','200.0.255.255',224], 
          ['192.24.8.1','108.0.8.8',304], ['192.0.25.1','228.0.38.1',128]]

option = input("If you would like to sort the list enter -s, anything esle will quit")

if option == "-s" :

    ip_list.sort (reverse = True)
    print (ip_list)
else :
    print ("Okay the list will not be sorted. Gooodbye!!")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from operator import itemgetter

ip_list = [['192.0.80.1','208.0.0.1', 34], ['192.0.80.1','200.0.255.255', 224], ['192.24.8.1', '108.0.8.8', 304], ['192.0.25.1', '228.0.38.1', 128]]

ip_sorted = sorted(ip_list, key=itemgetter(2), reverse=True)

print(ip_sorted)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[['192.24.8.1', '108.0.8.8', 304], ['192.0.80.1', '200.0.255.255', 224], ['192.0.25.1', '228.0.38.1', 128], ['192.0.80.1', '208.0.0.1', 34]]
```